# PHP & MySQL array problem

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the categories name from each array value from the database and then add the categories name to an array `$cat_name`, how can I do this using PHP & MySQL?

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

$cat_name = array();
$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT category 
                 FROM categories 
                 WHERE id = '" . $array . "'"); 


if (!$dbc) {
    print mysqli_error($mysqli);
} else {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)){
    $cat_name[] = $row['category'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT category 
                 FROM categories 
                 WHERE id IN (" .implode(",", $array). ")");
```

Comment: what if my array looks like this `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 34 ) `

Comment: what type of id is means interger, alphanum etc. 
if its numeric then this array can not be applied...
and the array must be single dimension otherwise u have to use SELECT query more than one...

Comment: ok fine... den u need:
$array2=new array();
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
 $array2[] = $v;
}

$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT category 
                 FROM categories 
                 WHERE id IN (" .implode(",", $array2). ")");

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT category 
    FROM categories
    WHERE id IN (" . implode(",", $array) . ")");
```

*However* when doing thing make sure your array actually contains only integers or you'll have a nasty SQL injection hole. If your array might contain something else, loop through it escaping all values and enclosing them in quotes before doing this.

Comment: what if my array looks like this `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 34 ) `

Comment: @leftout: ...that is an array of integers. Just make sure it's always like that.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good.  Am I right to presume that you are getting an error each time?  I don't think your SQL syntax is right.  I use 'WHERE id IN('.implode($array,',').')'.  Not sure whether this is your question...

EDIT:  I have the slight suspicion that you could also do away with your loop and instead simply issue a second fetch for the 'categories' column.

Comment: what if my array looks like this `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 34 ) `

Comment: I guess you could go implode(array_values($array),',').